# How is the mathematical term called?

Tags: terminology

I need help in identifying the underlining mathematical term of my method (group membership of a Person to an ideal role).

- So I have Ideal values (for the ideal role) shown here in the $1^{st}$ column (standardized mean values).
- The $2^{nd}$ column indicates the values of a Person $X$ (also standardized mean values).
- I want to see the deviation of the person's values from the ideal values. So in the $3^{rd}$ column, the difference will be taken.
- But for the case of calculating the absolute deviation in percentage only absolute differences will be taken into consideration ($4^{th}$ column).

> [image]

My next step is to calculate the sum of differences ($5^{th}$ column) and determine the percentage deviation by dividing the absolute difference for each value by the sum of difference ($6^{th}$ column).

Now my question is how is this term called? Can someone help me in this matter and is it understandable?

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds of different ways to find distances. The best site I found about that is [here](https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/CanberraDistance.html)

This came to mind since you are using both norms, and deviations. The linked site has some canned examples so you can try the distance formula. It also include the full description and the formula. I've linked to $Canberra \space Distance$, but please go up one level and look into all the articles. I think you will find your algorithm or something very similar.

https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, will definitely have a look at it!